# Error with saving audio through AVfoundation

Tags: swift, xcode, avfoundation

I learning IOS developing with IOS App Development course: https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud585/lessons/6991272773/concepts/70254815380923

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class RecordSoundsViewController: UIViewController{

    var audioRecorder: AVAudioRecorder!


    @IBOutlet weak var recordingLable: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var recordButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var stopRecordingButton: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        stopRecordingButton.isEnabled = false
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        print("viewWillAppear called")
    }

    @IBAction func recordAudio(_ sender: Any) {
        recordingLable.text = "Recording in progress"
        stopRecordingButton.isEnabled = true
        recordButton.isEnabled = false

        let dirPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory,.userDomainMask, true)[0] as String
        let recordingName = "recordedVoice.wav"
        let pathArray = [dirPath, recordingName]
        let filePath = URL(string: pathArray.joined(separator: "/"))

        let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        try! session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, with:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.defaultToSpeaker)

        try! audioRecorder = AVAudioRecorder(url: filePath!, settings: [:])
        audioRecorder.isMeteringEnabled = true
        audioRecorder.prepareToRecord()
        audioRecorder.record()
    }

    @IBAction func stopRecording(_ sender: Any) {
        recordButton.isEnabled = true
        stopRecordingButton.isEnabled = false
        recordingLable.text = "Tap to Record"
        audioRecorder.stop()
        let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        try! audioSession.setActive(false)

    }
}
```

Got error:

```
    viewWillAppear called
    2018-04-19 20:23:02.040084+0200 PitchPerfect[8899:6908132] 317:  ca_debug_string: inPropertyData == NULL
    2018-04-19 20:23:03.209361+0200 PitchPerfect[8899:6909411] [AudioHAL_Client] HALC_ProxyIOContext.cpp:1032:IOWorkLoop:  HALC_ProxyIOContext::IOWorkLoop: failed to send or receive the message from the server, Error: 0x10000003
    2018-04-19 20:23:03.211040+0200 PitchPerfect[8899:6909411] [AudioHAL_Client] HALC_ProxyIOContext.cpp:1399:IOWorkLoop:  HALC_ProxyIOContext::IOWorkLoop: failed to send the final message to the server, Error: 0x10000003
    2018-04-19 20:23:03.224866+0200 PitchPerfect[8899:6908870] [AudioHAL_Client] HALC_ProxySystem.cpp:143:GetObjectInfo:  HALC_ProxySystem::GetObjectInfo: got an error from the server, Error: 560947818 (!obj)
    2018-04-19 20:23:03.227916+0200 PitchPerfect[8899:6908870] [AudioHAL_Client] HALC_ShellDevice.cpp:3431:RebuildSubDeviceList:  HALC_ShellDevice::RebuildSubDeviceList: couldn't find the subdevice object
    2018-04-19 20:23:03.230117+0200 PitchPerfect[8899:6908870] [AudioHAL_Client] HALC_ProxySystem.cpp:143:GetObjectInfo:  HALC_ProxySystem::GetObjectInfo: got an error from the server, Error: 560947818 (!obj)
    2018-04-19 20:23:03.232075+0200 PitchPerfect[8899:6908870] [AudioHAL_Client] HALC_ShellDevice.cpp:3431:RebuildSubDeviceList:  HALC_ShellDevice::RebuildSubDeviceList: couldn't find the subdevice object
    2018-04-19 20:23:03.288995+0200 PitchPerfect[8899:6909488] [AudioHAL_Client] HALB_IOThread.cpp:251:_Start:  HALB_IOThread::_Start: there already is a thread
    2018-04-19 20:23:03.399056+0200 PitchPerfect[8899:6909537] [aqme] 1214: AQDefaultDevice: Abandoning I/O cycle because reconfig pending (1).
    2018-04-19 20:23:03.405536+0200 PitchPerfect[8899:6908872] 317:  ca_debug_string: inPropertyData == NULL
```

Comment: Your error occurs in some C++ library, so not much for us to work with. Your probably better of asking your course leader.

Comment: Set the `AVAudioRecorderDelegate` and implement `audioRecorderEncodeErrorDidOccur` to find out which, if any, errors are occurring. `AVFoundation` logs lots of negative sounding stuff, not all of which are user level errors.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try commenting the session configuring code.

```
// let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
// try! session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, with:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.defaultToSpeaker)
```

Comment: I declare `session` and use it in next line, if I comment it I'll get error

Comment: I mean comment both lines, don't configure it. Just test it out, it's to isolate the issue. If it didn't show any errors, that means, the error is due to the AVAudioSession configuration. 
Did you tried adding Audio Failed Delegate? and what did you received as error. Could you please add the details about that?

Comment: The 317 error in the console is coming from:  try! audioRecorder = AVAudioRecorder(url: filePath!, settings: [:])